# how do I make a envvar-modifying alias

Tags: bash

I run several Heroku apps from the same folder and I often need to target a specific one for a command I'm typing, through one of two environment variables

the options available to me are:

```
heroku command --app MYAPPID
heroku command -r MYAPPSGITREMOTEID
HEROKU_APP=MYAPPID heroku command
```

I currently use -r but it's difficult to build aliases with it, especially if I want to pipe the output of the heroku command to a different command... I can't call `myalias -r myappid` if the alias is `heroku command | tail`

I'd much prefer something like

`@production heroku command` that would evaluate to `HEROKU_APP=MYPRODUCTIONID heroku command`

bonus points if it'll work with chaining aliases, like `@production myalias` which would expand both the target app envvar alias and the command to be executed alias

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where shell functions are the perfect solution:

```
myheroku () {
    local heroku_app=$1
    shift
    env HEROKU_APP="$heroku_app" heroku "$@"
}

myalias1 () {
    myheroku "$1" specific command here
}
myalias2 () {
    myheroku "$1" some other command 
}
# ...
```

Then

```
myalias1 @production
```

Will eventually invoke

```
env HEROKU_APP="@production" heroku specific command here
```

Comment: I started down this road but got myself stuck trying to think about automatically handling `| tail` when stdout was a tty/etc. and gave up. But this would work with that on the `myheroku` function nicely I think.